# Computing Order of Galois Groups

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I would like to compute the order of Galois Group of following polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$. I am stuck here so I need some help

1. $X^4-1$
2. $X^4 -3$
3. $X^6+3$
4. $X^6-3$
5. $X^6+4$
6. $X^8+1$
7. $X^8+2$
8. $X^8-2$

Since we are talking about splitting fields over a field of characteristic $0$, they are Galois Extensions. Hence the order of the Galois Group is equal to the degree of the extension.

For the first two examples, It was very easy to determine the splitting fields but it gets complicated for me after that. I would appreciate if someone can shed some light over $(c)-(g)$. I really need this to proceed further with Galois Theory.

Comment: How, specifically, do you find (4) harder than (2), for example?

Comment: In these equations you typically get a dihedral Galois group.

Comment: @GregMartin, The splitting field of $x^4-3$ can be obtained by adjoining solutions of $x^4-1$ and ${3}^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and it was easier to proceed further. Now regarding $(4)$, The equation is of degree $6$ and I really don't know how to compute the splitting field

Comment: Review *roots of unity*. I'm fairly sure they are explained in your book. You simply need sixth or eighth roots of unity in the later exercises unlike the fourth roots of unity in the first two.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

$4.$
The roots are $\alpha\omega^k$, where $\alpha=\sqrt[6]{3}$ and $\omega$ is a sixth-root of unity. So the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega) $. Note that $\omega=1/2+i\sqrt3/2$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega)=
\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt3 i)$. But $\sqrt3=\alpha^3\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt3 i)$, so the splitting field simplifies to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$. Since one generator is complex and the other is real, is easy to compute that the degree of extension is $12$. A group of order $12$ generated by a element of order $6$ and another of order $2$... It seems like dihedral group. Try proving it finding two automorphisms that give the structure to the group.

$6.$
Note that $x^8+1$ is the cyclotomic polynomial of order $16$ so it's Galois group is directly derived from here.

The cases $3,5,6,7$ are very similar to the $4$.